# SpamAssassin ASN Plugin

Tags: perl, spamassassin, as-number

I've got spamassassin 3.4.0 setup to use **Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::ASN**. cpan confirms that it is installed, and dig confirms that I can get the ASN TXT records from http://routeviews.org. My `local.cf` has this section:

```
#####   Autonomous System Plugin
# https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.4.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Plugin_ASN.html
ifplugin Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::ASN
asn_lookup      asn.routeviews.org _ASN_ _ASNCIDR_
asn_prefix      "AS"
add_header      all ASN _ASN_ _ASNCIDR_
endif
```

Yet, whenever I look at the headers in a message, the ASN section is blank:

```
Return-Path: <PersonalizedGiftMall@gradgiftspersonalized.eu>
X-Original-To: justin@justinzane.com
Delivered-To: justin@justinzane.com
Received: by jz-rs-01.justinzane.com (Postfix, from userid 182) id CE91A1AAB8; Tue, 20 May 2014 21:48:32 +0000 (UTC)
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on jz-rs-01.justinzane.com
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No, score=3.5 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_80, HTML_FONT_LOW_CONTRAST,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RDNS_NONE shortcircuit=no autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
X-Spam-ASN:  
Received: from w2ynk.gradgiftspersonalized.eu (unknown [170.130.150.45]) by jz-rs-01.justinzane.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id 90C381AAB3 for <justin@justinzane.com>; Tue, 20 May 2014 21:48:16 +0000 (UTC)
Received: by 0166d6ef.w2ynk.gradgiftspersonalized.eu (amavisd-new, port 3565) with ESMTP id 01OL66D6DWEF; for <justin@justinzane.com>; Tue, 20 May 2014 14:48:18 -0700
Date: Tue, 20 May 2014 14:48:18 -0700
Message-ID: <156514423515346156556320117864450@w2ynk.gradgiftspersonalized.eu>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
From: Personalized Gift Mall <PersonalizedGiftMall@gradgiftspersonalized.eu>
Subject: Personalized Graduation Invites, Banners, and Gifts
Content-Language: en-us
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
To: justin@justinzane.com
```

Additionally, running `spamassassing -t -D < /path/to/spam.message` shows that the ASN plugin is "getting" the proper data. But, somehow the header is not being written. Can someone please help me determine how to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this myself and figured I'd respond since there isn't an answer. The answer is actually that you're sending mail to yourself through the same mail server, which is normally the first thing anyone does to test a change to mail server configuration.

As far as I can tell, anything that is in your list trusted networks isn't considered a relay for SpamAssassin's purposes, so the module can't get an ASN for that. The moment an external relay connects, you get ASN data.